# Restrict generic types in java based on implementation of generic interface

Tags: java, generics

So I have got 2 generic interfaces.

First interface is implemented like this.

```
public interface First<E>
{
   void method(E e)
}

public class FirstImpl implements First<String>
{
   void method(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
}

public class FirstImpl2 implements First<Double>
{
    void method(Double d) { System.out.println(d); }
}
```

I need the second interface's (second interface is shown below) generic type to allow only the classes that are used when implementing the first interface, in our case `String` and `Double`. Is there any clean way to do this, something like

```
public interface Second <E, ? extends First<E>>
{
    void method(E e);
}

public class SecondImpl <E> implements Second <E, ? extends First<E>>
{
    void method(E e) { System.out.println(e); }
}
```

, so the in Second's generic `E` would fit only `String` and `Double` and all classes that are used to implement `First<E>`?

Comment: That looks reasonable.  What do you want to do with `T`?

Comment: How would you prevent adding a different implementation of `First<E>`? Or is that not a problem? (Your idea should just work otherwise.)

Comment: I don't need T, guess I could place a wildcard there, it doesn't work anyway.
I need this to work with all implementations of First<E>.

I have just edited the code, so instead of T is a wildcard.

Comment: Are you saying you want to prevent having e.g. a `Second<Float>` because there isn't a `FirstImpl3 implements First<Float>`? No, that's not possible. Otherwise, please edit the question and clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: @GolovaciLena I am not sure if `Second` will compile.

Comment: Not a Second<Float>, more like a 
class SecondImpl <E, ? extends First<E>> implements Second <E, ? extends First<E>>
{
 method(E e) { System.out.println(e); }
}

where e couldn't be Float if there isn't a FirstImpl3 implements First<Float>

Comment: @GolovaciLena But that's nonsensical, non-existent syntax so it doesn't mean anything to us. Again, please edit the question and try to flesh out the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just have `interface Second<E>` with methods like `void method(First<E>)`.

Comment: @Radiodef I'll try to edit my question, so it would be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @VGR because First<E> and E would be different classes, and I need E, not implementation of First<E>.

Comment: @Radiodef, I am trying to obtain an answer to the question posted at the beginning of the page.

Comment: There is no way to have generics, or any other syntax, require that a Java class with specific attributes exists somewhere in the JVM or classpath.

Comment: Please take a look at the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? The question asks about a way that you think you could solve it (some kind of generic bound) to which the answer is only "no, it's not possible". If you want an answer besides "it's not possible", edit the question to more clearly explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You can not restrict the generic type of the Second in that sense. You can still provide an another type information independently. Say,

```
class XYZ implements First<Bar> { ... }
```

an another class may provide an another type information for the Second, like

```
class ZYX implements Second<Foo, SomeOtherType<Foo>> { ... }
```

assuming SomeOtherType implements/extends whatever from type First. If you want to bind those two interfaces on their generic type, you can use inheritance between the implementations:

```
  interface First<T> {}
  interface Second<T> {}
  class Foo<E extends T> implements First<T> {}
  class Bar<E extends T> extends Foo<E> implements Second<E> {}
```

Now, the type E, is associated with the type T, via E extends T.